# Closet door replacement from 36" to 48" wide

Tags: doors, installation, closet

I want to remove my old fold-in 36" door, expand the opening to fit two 24" doors (with hinges) and frame.  I want to know what is the exact width of the closet opening to fit that?

Paolo

Comment: No one can answer this without a lot more info, and pictures.  Is the wall wood frame and drywall? Brick? Concrete?  You get the idea.  Where on the planet are you located? Construction standards vary

Comment: Also will you be adding 6” on each side? Or 12” to one side or the other?  Is the wall load bearing?

Comment: 24" doors with hinges - do you mean bi-fold doors?  Pretty much most doors use hinges.  Ones that don't are usually called windows or panels...

Comment: Google rough opening for double doors